# Are there any airline flights from Deer Lake to St. John's?

Tags: air-travel, canada, airlines, newfoundland

My first cousin once removed fancies travelling to Newfoundland, mainly to sightsee Gros Morne National Park and then St. John's. [Multiple Tripadvisor commenters say that the 8-hour drive is unworthy and not scenic](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g580445-i10639-k8070468-Driving_from_St_Johns_to_Gros_Morne-Gros_Morne_National_Park_Newfoundland_Newfoundland_and.html). So can she fly instead?

I think not: [Air Canada Express](https://flyjazz.ca/en/operations/air-canada-express/) indicates the only destination from Deer Lake as Halifax. 
But I thought to check here.

Comment: Flight search engines are usually the best way to find this out, and indeed they show such flights.  Airline websites are less reliable, as you found, because in some cases your guess about which airline operates or markets the flight might be wrong.

Comment: Multiple Tripadvisor commentators are correct about the drive itself, but fail to take into account the many things you can stop off and see along the way.

Comment: I strongly recommend that your first cousin once removed continues north to L'Anse-aux-Meadows and, depending on season, St. Anthony and the icebergs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Deer Lake Airport site](http://www.deerlakeairport.com/airlines/passenger/) says that [PAL Airlines](http://www.palairlines.ca/) operates flights from Deer Lake to St. John's, and their website seems to confirm that (on Dash-8 aircraft).

Air Canada and their partners also operate this route. [The current timetable](https://services.aircanada.com/portal/rest/timetable/pdf/ac-timetable-en.pdf?locale=en&app_key=AE919FDCC80311DF9BABC975DFD72085) lists 3 flights a day (on Beech 1900 aircraft), though they may reduce frequencies after summer. The flights are not operated by Jazz, so they are not listed on the flyjazz.ca site.